# Applicationbar without three dots using windows phone

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1

How can i add application bar with out three dots.

Comment: What is the reason for you wanting to display the Application Bar without the three dots?

Comment: That is completed related to client requirement .Application start page is not looking great with that three dots , so i want to remove those thing

Comment: The client seems to have misunderstood Windows Phone then.

Answer (score 4):

You can't add a applicationbar without the default layout. The 3 dots indicate to the user that they can click it, and get a description of the applicationbar buttons.

This is good UX, and makes your application feel intuitive to the user.

Answer (score 1):

If it is important to you to have this kind of effect, you'll have to roll your own.

In essence (and it isn't quite this simple for a variety of reasons) you'll have to split your main view into a grid with a dedicated row at the bottom into which you can add your own icons.

```
<Grid Name="MainLayoutArea">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="40" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid Name="LayoutRoot">
        <!-- your main page stuff hewre, presumably wrapped in a scroll viewer -->
    </Grid>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="1">
        <!-- add your buttons here, styled appropriately -->
    </StackPanel>
<Grid>
```

**I wouldn't recommend doing it, though** - your users may become confused about what the icons are without the ability to expand the application bar and see the labels - user expectation is a powerful thing, and there may even be an argument for Microsoft to reject your app from the store based on this.

Comment: Things like theme-adjustment, and page-orientation would also make it very difficult to roll your own.

Comment: If i place the buttons inside the grid,there is a problem with more data. if there is more data then buttons are also moves down. Then there is no use of it

Comment: Abslutely agree, Claus - there are so many gotchas for doing this that it makes the effort crazy for all but a tiny subset of possible scenarios.

Comment: @kishore - that is why the ScrollViewer control is inside LayoutRoot, but you need to explicitly size it so it doesn't push anything down

Comment: Anyway, the point it that you can't do what you want with the supplied ApplicationBar control, so you'd have to do it yourself if the 3 dots are so awful your client can't possibly live with them